# No sound after installing Nvidia graphics card

Tags: drivers

I bought GeForce GT 710 graphics card and it seems that its sound system disables my built-in sound card.

My PC is a little bit old and the latest update of sound card drivers is compatible with Windows 7. For many reasons, I'd like to use Windows 10.

In the past, I used the generic audio drivers that comes with Windows 10. Now, it seems that the drivers of the graphics card override the generic audio drivers of Windows 10.

How can I use Windows 10 sound drivers to run my old built-in sound card? Can I use Windows repair or something like that to reinstall the drivers? Are there general drivers that are compatible with Windows 10 and run Intel sound cards?

Comment: Did you install the latest Windows 10 update?

Comment: @Keltari, would it help?

Comment: probably not. The latest update pushed the wrong audio driver for Intel sound. I thought maybe that might have been your issue.

Comment: @Keltari I prefer waiting for other answers and opinions because installing a new windows takes time and effort for me :) Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: You can disable audio output from your graphics card from the Nvidia control panel, this should mean that Windows doesn't look at your card as an audio device. It's under the "Digital Audio" section I believe

Comment: Worth pointing out your default audio device likelywas simply reset because your Nvidia GPU doesn’t have a built-in audio device.

Comment: It is really a strange issue, I don't think it is cased by Nvidia driver. Have you try to reinstall your sound card driver?

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe that the NVidia card should be disabling the Intel sound card. I've never seen such behavior before.

Try downloading and running the [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) software. It should detect your Intel sound card and install the latest driver for it.  Also note if there are any errors during any driver updates.

At best, this resolves the issue. At worst, you know you are running  the  correct and most up-to-date driver for your Intel sound chipset.

Update us with any new information.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right at guessing that it *may* be a simple issue, then it should be quick to resolve. In Windows 10 go to Sound Settings, either via right clicking the speakers icon in the taskbar or via Settings (Windows Key, then right click on Windows Icon), then System, Sound.

NVIDIA Install may have changed your sound settings so that on the top of the sound settings page NVIDIA sound is selected as output. If so then change (back) to your original sound output. ("Choose your output device.)
If this fixes it, then fine. If this is a more complex issue, pardon.

NVIDIA Sound Output:
[image: NVIDIA Output]

Original Speakers Output:
[image: Speakers Output]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with a GT710 in Windows 10.
My HP motherboard Realtek ALC262 sound card is no longer an available option in Device Manager after I install the GT710, only the NVIDIA HDMI is available.
When I swap back to the old video card the Realtek sound card becomes an option in Device Manager again.